# How to check S3 bucket and local repository is completely synced or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 bucket repository of size around 45 GB & want to clone on local system, So i run command "aws s3 sync s3://***** D:**** --delete". when i returned the command line is closed, So i want to check that S3 bucket & my local repository is in synced or not.

Comment: You can compare the size of bucket with your local destination if you have not used `--exclude`.

Comment: Thanks  franklinsijo, but i have no desktop/visual access to the S3 bucket, i have only command line access to the bucket.

Comment: It seems like the only safe action is to repeat the *sync* process.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the result of sizes between your bucket and the local destination assuming you didn't use `--exclude` in your sync.

To calculate the size of bucket,

`aws s3 ls bucketname --recursive --summarize --human-readable | grep 'Total Size:'`

Similarly you can use linux `du` command to get the local directory size.

**Note:** It is easier to get the S3 bucket or object sizes with `s3cmd`.